# Passing more variables to php file upload

Tags: jquery

I have a file upload, but I need to be able to pass other form data to it. Mainly so I can make the php dynamic and pass what category the file is so it's put in the right folder. Not fond of creating the same exact function ten times just to change one line.

I have tried passing it in the ajax as so through the data

```
data: {
        form_data:form_data,
        fileType:fileType
      },
```

and I have tried appending it using the file data, but that's not working as well.

```
form_data.append('file_up', file_data);
form_data.append('file_up', fileType);
```

Is there something I am missing? i need to be able to get that fileType through to the php.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell what your problem might be without seeing more of your code.

Your second approach ought to work, using the `form_data.append`. (I'm guessing the fact that you've named both appends "file_up" is just a typo?)

Here is a working example (server and client side code):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#s').click(function() {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append("file_up", $('#f')[0].files[0]);
        form_data.append("file_type", $('#t').val());
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#output').html(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<input id="f" type="file"/>
<input id="t" type="text"/>
<button id="s">Submit</button>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

and a corresponding PHP page:

```
<pre><?php

echo '$_FILES:<br>';
print_r($_FILES);

echo '<br><br>$_REQUEST:<br>';
print_r($_REQUEST);


?></pre>
```

If the code doesn't help, you might try using the browser developer tools, network tab, to see if you can determine if the problem is client or server side. When submitting your ajax call, your XHR request payload should look something like this:

```
-----------------------------16516352471776150483721558073
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_up"; filename="test.php.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

......BINARY FILE DATA HERE......

-----------------------------16516352471776150483721558073
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_type"

lsajdflkajdf
-----------------------------16516352471776150483721558073--
```

This is from Firefox; I'm assuming Chrome probably gives comparable information.

If you don't have a second form-data section for your file type, then the problem is likely somewhere in your javascript. (In which case it would be helpful if you could post some more of your ajax/FormData code).

If the section is there, then the problem is most likely somewhere on the server side. (In which case it would be helpful if you could post the section of your server side code where you are trying to read the `$_REQUEST` data, or maybe do a `print_r` or `var_dump` of the `$_REQUEST`)